Configuring Kubernetes to Use Private Docker Registry (HTTP/HTTPS) with Self-Signed Certificate Without Restarting Docker
I’m working on configuring Kubernetes to pull images from a private Docker registry that uses a self-signed certificate. My setup has a couple of constraints:

The Docker registry is either HTTP or HTTPS with a self-signed certificate.

I cannot restart the Docker service to apply changes.

I need Kubernetes to pull images from this registry without issues related to the self-signed certificate.


Could someone please guide me on how to configure Kubernetes so that it can interact with this Docker registry without requiring a Docker restart? Specifically, I am interested in:

How to set up Kubernetes to trust a self-signed certificate for a Docker registry.

Any Kubernetes configurations or secrets needed for this purpose.

If there are any specific steps or best practices to follow.


Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I expected that by configuring Kubernetes to recognize and trust the self-signed certificate, it would be able to pull images from the private registry without issues.

I was hoping for a method to configure Kubernetes or Docker within the cluster itself to handle the self-signed certificate properly without requiring a Docker restart.



Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
